# Will fuerte have an Ubuntu 10.04 installation?

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ubuntu-lucid, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on Ubuntu Lucid (10.04 LTS) and I do not plan to move to Ubuntu 11.XX or Ubuntu 12.XX. I wished to enquire if the upcoming ROS release of fuerte will have an Ubuntu 10.04 installation ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12640/will-fuerte-have-an-ubuntu-10.04-installation-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, see: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-14**:
@dornhege Thank you